# Python - Selenium next page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to make a scraping application to scrape Hants.gov.uk and right now I am working on it just clicking the pages instead of scraping. When it gets to the last row on page 1 it just stopped, so what I did was make it click button "Next Page" but first it has to go back to the original URL. It clicks page 2, but after page 2 is scraped it doesn't go to page 3, it just restarts page 2.

Can somebody help me fix this issue?

Code:

```
import time
import config # Don't worry about this. This is an external file to make a DB
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://planning.hants.gov.uk/SearchResults.aspx?RecentDecisions=True"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("mainContentPlaceHolder_btnAccept").click()

def start():
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".searchResult a")
    links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in elements]

    result = []
    for link in links:
        if link not in result:
            result.append(link)
        else:
            driver.get(link)
            goUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(goUrl.read(), "html.parser")
            #table = soup.find_element_by_id("table", {"class": "applicationDetails"})
            for i in range(20):
                pass # Don't worry about all this commented code, it isn't relevant right now
                #table = soup.find_element_by_id("table", {"class": "applicationDetails"})
                #print(table.text)
            #   div = soup.select("div.applicationDetails")
            #   getDiv = div[i].split(":")[1].get_text()
            #   log = open("log.txt", "a")
            #   log.write(getDiv + "\n")
            #log.write("\n")

start()
driver.get(url)

for i in range(5):
    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lvResults_bottomPager_ctl02_NextButton").click()
    url = driver.current_url
    start()
    driver.get(url)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this:**

```
import time
# import config # Don't worry about this. This is an external file to make a DB
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://planning.hants.gov.uk/SearchResults.aspx?RecentDecisions=True"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("mainContentPlaceHolder_btnAccept").click()

result = []


def start():
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".searchResult a")
    links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in elements]
    result.extend(links)

def start2():
    for link in result:
        # if link not in result:
        #     result.append(link)
        # else:
            driver.get(link)
            goUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(goUrl.read(), "html.parser")
            #table = soup.find_element_by_id("table", {"class": "applicationDetails"})
            for i in range(20):
                pass # Don't worry about all this commented code, it isn't relevant right now
                #table = soup.find_element_by_id("table", {"class": "applicationDetails"})
                #print(table.text)
            #   div = soup.select("div.applicationDetails")
            #   getDiv = div[i].split(":")[1].get_text()
            #   log = open("log.txt", "a")
            #   log.write(getDiv + "\n")
            #log.write("\n")


while True:
    start()
    element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rdpPageNext')
    try:
        check = element.get_attribute('onclick')
        if check != "return false;":
            element.click()
        else:
            break

    except:
        break

print(result)
start2()
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Yeah but the code also is required to check through each application too. There are 7 each page

Comment: it is checking. i used while loop

Comment: use sleep in between loop. as per requirment. i can't run the code right now. but i think this will work fine

Comment: i thought you had problem to go through each page. so i solved only that. you have to add your other code to get data from table.  you can add that just after the line `while True:`

Comment: tell me if this is working or not. if it is i will explain the logic

Comment: Where exactly do I put my code? You don't specify and you removed most of it anyways

Comment: You have removed nearly all the relevant code, which instead of helping my code, breaks it

Comment: Once it gets to the last application it just pauses and doesn't continue to the next page

Comment: check this its working now. i have first extracted all the links then go through each of those later

Answer (score 1):

As per the url `https://planning.hants.gov.uk/SearchResults.aspx?RecentDecisions=True` to click through all the pages you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://planning.hants.gov.uk/SearchResults.aspx?RecentDecisions=True')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mainContentPlaceHolder_btnAccept"))).click()
  numLinks = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lvResults_topPager div.rdpWrap.rdpNumPart>a"))))
  print(numLinks)
  for i in range(numLinks):
      print("Perform your scrapping here on page {}".format(str(i+1)))
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='ctl00_mainContentPlaceHolder_lvResults_topPager']//div[@class='rdpWrap rdpNumPart']//a[@class='rdpCurrentPage']/span//following::span[1]"))).click()
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  8
  Perform your scrapping here on page 1
  Perform your scrapping here on page 2
  Perform your scrapping here on page 3
  Perform your scrapping here on page 4
  Perform your scrapping here on page 5
  Perform your scrapping here on page 6
  Perform your scrapping here on page 7
  Perform your scrapping here on page 8
  ```

Comment: Although this is a splendid idea I would like to accomplish this task with mostly my own code, I am just trying to figure it out :) Thank you though

Comment: @FeitanPortor We are neither aware about your _requirement_ nor about your _usecase_. You have raised your question and contributors are trying to help you out in their own capacity. Feel free to use either the _code_ or the _logic_ within :) it would be your choice

Comment: I know. This doesn't precisely answer my question. I upvoted earlier

Answer (score 0):

hi @Feitan Portor you have written the code absolutely perfect the only reason that you are redirected back to the first page is because you have given `url = driver.current_url` in the last for loop where it is the url that remains static and only the java script that instigates the next click event so just remove `url = driver.current_url` and `driver.get(url)`

and you are good to go i have tested my self
also to get  the current page that your scraper is in just add this part in the for loop so you will get to know where your scraper is :

```
ss = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rdpCurrentPage').text
    print(ss)
```

Hope this solves your confusion

Comment: I get an error https://pastebin.com/jZPCpdjB
It manages to get to page 2, but no more